# How to display loading only on table body in antd without any custom css?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my Reactapp i have a table component [image]

I just want to know can i display the loading insert into table body only without any custom css? Done a lot of research but found nothing can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like below:

```
const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);    

function getData(){
setSpinner(true);

 //som asyn process
 fetch('your api'), {
    method: 'post'
    body: body,
 }).then(function(data){
 setSpinner(false);
 };
}
```

Your table body:

```
<table>
   <head>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <body>
     {spinner? 'loading....' :(
         <tr>your td</tr>
     )} 
   </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: i get your idea but i need to done this task without any custom css and in ant design way only!

Comment: This is not CSS, this is react.

Comment: yes but i need it in ant design way!

Comment: Please add some code to understand better. add you table code